# How do I merge these 2 MySQL queries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries, that are almost exactly the same.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    cman_code, cman_name 
FROM
    capder 
JOIN 
    caprange ON capder.cder_rancode = caprange.cran_code 
JOIN 
    capman ON caprange.cran_mantextcode = capman.cman_code 
JOIN 
    capmod ON capder.cder_modcode = capmod.cmod_code 
JOIN 
    nvdtechnical ON nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID 
JOIN 
    nvddictionarytechnical ON nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = nvdtechnical.TECH_TechCode 
JOIN 
    nvddictionarycategory ON nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode = nvddictionarytechnical.DT_CatCode 
JOIN 
    nvdmodelyear ON capder.cder_ID = MY_Id
                    AND nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 67 
                    AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < '100' 
                    AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float != 0      
                    AND cder_transmission = 'M' 
                    AND cman_code IN ('1','140','164','836','869','1283','1333','1925','2193','2514','4256','4537','4721','4835','5088','5171','5182','5238','5261','5509','6058','6425','7104','7983','8083','8219','9909','10172','10251','10383','10519','10968','12243','12764','14786','15155','21223','22439','44394','47841') 
                    AND (cmod_discontinued=0 OR cmod_discontinued=2015) 
                    AND cder_discontinued = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
    cman_code 
ORDER BY 
    cman_name DESC
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    cman_code, cman_name 
FROM 
    capder 
JOIN 
    caprange ON capder.cder_rancode = caprange.cran_code 
JOIN 
    capman ON caprange.cran_mantextcode = capman.cman_code 
JOIN 
    capmod ON capder.cder_modcode = capmod.cmod_code 
JOIN 
    nvdtechnical ON nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID 
JOIN 
    nvddictionarytechnical ON nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = nvdtechnical.TECH_TechCode 
JOIN 
    nvddictionarycategory ON nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode = nvddictionarytechnical.DT_CatCode 
JOIN 
    nvdmodelyear ON capder.cder_ID = MY_Id
WHERE 
    nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 11 
    AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < 25  
    AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float != 0
    AND cder_transmission = 'M' 
    AND cman_code IN ('1','140','164','836','869','1283','1333','1925','2193','2514','4256','4537','4721','4835','5088','5171','5182','5238','5261','5509','6058','6425','7104','7983','8083','8219','9909','10172','10251','10383','10519','10968','12243','12764','14786','15155','21223','22439','44394','47841') 
    AND (cmod_discontinued=0 OR cmod_discontinued=2015) 
    AND cder_discontinued = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
    cman_code 
ORDER BY 
    cman_name DESC
```

Both queries work perfectly and produce the exact results what I want.

The only difference between the two is the values in `nvddictionarytechnical.**DT_TechCode**` and `nvdtechnical.**TECH_Value_Float**`

I am having trouble bringing them together.

The - **TECH_Value_Float** - column, contains both **CO2** and **MPG** values.

I just need to merge these into 1 query.

Using this does not work:

```
where 
(
   (
     nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 67 
     AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < '100'
   ) 
   or 
   (
     nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 11 
     AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < 25
   )
 )
```

The where and or produce results like:

```
|CO2 | MPG|
-----------
 94  | 78 |
 378 | 19 |
```

I need for the MPG and CO2 to both be true.
And results like:

```
|CO2 | MPG|
-----------
 15  | 18 |
 10  | 17 |
```

Any advice from the pros? Should I just make 2 queries? Has anyone ever come across a problem like this? Is this very unusual?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
where 
(
   (
     nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 67 
     AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < '100'
   ) 
   or 
   (
     nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 11 
     AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < 25
   )
 )
```

Comment: Beat me to it by the click of a submit button. You win... :-)

Comment: I have tried this thank you. It does not work. Both need to be true for the row to qualify. I need to say - give me the MAKE that has x MPG value and also x CO2 value. They both work perfect separate - just cant figure how to do them together. I think I need to re merge tables again?? Not sure.. or maybe 2 queries ???

Comment: The **where** and **or** are producing results like MPG 78 and CO2 94
OR  MPG 19 and CO2 378.

It cant be either - it needs to be both true

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT cman_code, cman_name 

from capder 

JOIN caprange ON capder.cder_rancode = caprange.cran_code 
JOIN capman ON caprange.cran_mantextcode = capman.cman_code 
JOIN capmod ON capder.cder_modcode = capmod.cmod_code 
JOIN nvdtechnical ON nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID 
JOIN nvddictionarytechnical ON nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = nvdtechnical.TECH_TechCode 
JOIN nvddictionarycategory ON nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode = nvddictionarytechnical.DT_CatCode 
JOIN nvdmodelyear ON capder.cder_ID = MY_Id

AND ((nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 67 
       AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < '100') 
   OR (nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 11 
       AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float < 25 ))

AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float != 0      

AND cder_transmission = 'M' 
AND cman_code IN ('1','140','164','836','869','1283','1333','1925','2193','2514','4256','4537','4721','4835','5088','5171','5182','5238','5261','5509','6058','6425','7104','7983','8083','8219','9909','10172','10251','10383','10519','10968','12243','12764','14786','15155','21223','22439','44394','47841') 

AND (cmod_discontinued=0 OR cmod_discontinued=2015) 
AND cder_discontinued = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY cman_code ORDER BY cman_name DESC
```

That way you check for both of the conditions!